# Oracle SQL - substr parameter hardcoding

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with column "foo" that its datatype is varchar2(100).

In this table I've got a row with some information in "foo" column. Let's say it is string "bar".

Then I have a procedure that makes copy of row, changes the data and insert it to the table. One of changes is to add string "xyz, " in "foo" column at the beginning and concatenate the rest. So when I run this procedure it makes row that has string "xyz, bar" in "foo" column.
The next time I run this procedure I would get string "abc, xyz, bar" in "foo" column, etc.

To not run into an error I write my code like that:

```
Insert into table (
foo
) values (
substr(variable_with_additional_string || variable_with_string_from_foo_column, 1, 100)
);
```

I always cut the last part if a string is too long.

But what if someone alters table and changes the datatype of column "foo" to varchar2(80)? My procedure will not work anymore.

So my question is: How to not hardcode number 100 in substr() function?

My only idea is to

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'foo';
```

and find number using regular expressions or other functions but I do not think that is the optimal way so solve this issue.

Comment: are you sure about the columns contenet a INSERT INTO wouldn't do that , wjach you can test in any dbfoddle

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you worry about that "someone" changing the type length but not, say, the whole type to integer, or renaming the column, or dropping it altogether?

Comment: @nbk yes I am sure. I did it today, you can try it at https://livesql.oracle.com
create table t1 (foo varchar2(100));
insert into t1 (foo) values (substr('abc, ' || 'bar', 1, 7));
select * from t1;

Comment: @Quassnoi Maybe there is no need to worry. I just try to avoid hardcoding as much as possible. What is the point of changing datetype to integer when there are strings already? Renaming a column would make most of the packages stop working but everywhere I see there are variables with t1.foo%TYPE;. And there are for a reason, changing datetype of column would not mess with %type variables so I would like to do something similar with my substr. Of course I am thinking about another way to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a simple select query to get a data length of your column, for example:

```
SELECT DATA_LENGTH
INTO v_max_length
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'foo'
AND OWNER= 'your_schema_name'-- thanks for a good point made by MT0 in comment section.
```

And then use that value in your insert's substr function:

```
Insert into table 
(
   foo
) 
values 
(
    substr(variable_with_additional_string || variable_with_string_from_foo_column, 1, v_max_length)
);
```

Comment: You also need to filter on the `owner` column otherwise you will get multiple rows returned if tables with the same name and column name exists in multiple schemas.

Comment: Ofcourse you are right, thank you for valueable comment @MT0. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict length of a string up to column's length, I don't think you can do it in SQL - but you can in PL/SQL, writing a procedure which will modify that table. Here's an example.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, col varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Procedures checks `user_tab_columns` and uses `merge` to *upsert* `col` column with a substring of `par_col` parameter (concatenated to previous column contents) up to max column length.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_id  in test.id%type,
  3     par_col in test.col%type)
  4  is
  5    l_data_length user_tab_columns.data_length%type;
  6  begin
  7    select data_length
  8      into l_data_length
  9      from user_tab_columns
 10      where table_name = 'TEST'
 11        and column_name = 'COL';
 12
 13    merge into test a
 14      using (select par_id  as id,
 15                    par_col as col
 16             from dual
 17            ) x
 18      on (a.id = x.id)
 19      when matched then update set
 20        a.col = substr(par_col || ','|| a.col, 1, l_data_length)
 21      when not matched then insert (id, col)
 22        values (par_id, substr(par_col, 1, l_data_length));
 23  end;
 24  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test (1, 'abc');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- ----------
         1 abc

SQL> exec p_test(1, '12345678');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- ----------
         1 12345678,a
```

You worry about *shortening* column's length; that might, or might not be possible (in a simple manner):

```
SQL> alter table test modify col varchar2(5);
alter table test modify col varchar2(5)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01441: cannot decrease column length because some value is too big
```

One option is to shorten existing contents first:

```
SQL> update test set col = substr(col, 1, 5);

1 row updated.

SQL> alter table test modify col varchar2(5);

Table altered.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- -----
         1 12345
```

Let's test again:

```
SQL> exec p_test (1, 'xyz');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- -----
         1 xyz,1

SQL>
```

On the other hand, why do you let anyone alter tables?